# Ruby does string equal one of the strings in an array of strings?

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

Is there an easy way to sort of call something similar to the database In query?

Does "mystring" exist in ["string1","mystring","string2"] => would return true

Does "mystring" exist in ["string1","string2","string3"] => would return false

Answer (score 12):

```
["string1","mystring","string2"].include? "mystring"
```

See: [Enumerable#include?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Enumerable.html#method-i-include-3F)